# decreasing sequence of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $μ$ a measure on a set $X$ and let $g_{n}∈L_{1}(X, μ)$ a decreasing sequence of integrable functions. Suppose that $g_{n}(x) → g(x)$. prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_{n}(x)dμ=0\iff g (x)=0~~~~\text{a.e.} $$

Comment: Hint: Apply Monotone Convergence theorem.

Comment: but the functions are decreasing and are not necessarily positive.

Comment: Hint: apply it to $-g_n$

Comment: but the functions can be non-negative or non-positive or both.and the monotone convergence theorem is for sequences no-negative.

Comment: Alexander: There are special cases of monotone convergence you may be most familiar with, but it applies in the following situations:  (1) The sequence is increasing and bounded below by an integrable function. In this case, $+\infty$ is a possible value of the limit.  (2) The sequence is decreasing and bounded above by an integrable function.  In this case, $-\infty$ is a possible value of the limit.  This is the case that applies to your situation, because all functions are bounded above by $g_1$.  To get the version of MCT you like, consider $(g_1-g_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.  Consider $g(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and $g_n=g$ for all $n$.

If you meant to include the hypothesis that $g_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, then as Stefan commented, applying the monotone (or dominated) convergence theorem  (or Fatou's lemma) is a good idea.