# Integral of limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am working on a problem$^{(1)}$ similar to this 2013 [*posting*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289581/decreasing-sequence-of-integrable-functions):

> Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of integrable, non-negative functions, so that $\forall x$, $f_n(x)$ decreases to $f(x)$. Show the following is true:
>   $$\int f_n d \mu \rightarrow \int f d \mu.$$

Aside from the apparent differences between the two questions, this problem comes from early chapter of Measure & Integration class, so that Monotone Convergence Theorem is not in the background. Here are what I have been attempting to do $-$ rightly or wrongly:

Since $f_n(x)$ decreases to $f(x)$, this implies that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x). \tag{1}$$

Taking integral on both sides,
$$\begin{align}
\int \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) d \mu = \int f(x) d \mu \tag{2}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n(x) d \mu = \int f(x) d \mu \tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

implying that

$$\int f_n d \mu \rightarrow \int f d \mu. \tag{4}$$

But I am not sure if the move from (2) to (3) is valid. Please let me know what I should do instead. Thank you for your time and help.

---

(1) Richard F. Bass' [*Real Analysis*](http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real-analysis-04nov2011.pdf), 2nd. edition, chapter 6: The Lebesgue Integration, Exercise 6.6, page 50.

Comment: The interchange of integration and limit in step (3) is generally not permitted

Comment: The move from (2) to (3) is essentially the meat of the problem.  In general, we cannot arbitrarily move limits in and out of integrals. Have you discussed Fatou's lemma?

Comment: Hint: consider the functions $g_n = f_n - f_1$. They form an increasing sequence of positive functions. Apply Beppo Levi.

Comment: @Brandon : No, Fatou's lemma is not in the background, this lemma will only be covered on chapter 7. Thanks.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas : No again, Beppo Levi is not even listed on the book's index. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems as though you are forced to use the definition. Consider simple functions $s$ satisfying $f\leq s\leq f_n$ and show that $\int|f-f_n|d\mu=0$.

Comment: @Brandon : Let me try and will get back with you. Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon : I recall that in the previous exercise from the same text, it has been proven that there exists simple function $s_n$ increasing to $f$ at each point. Since it is defined $\int f d\mu = \sup \{\int s d \mu \mid 0 \leq s \leq f\},$ can it be that
$$\int f d\mu - \int f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu - \sup \{\int s_n d\mu\} = 0$$
because the supremum of $\int s_n d\mu$ will eventually catching up with $\int f d\mu$? Does it make sense? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my previous reply.

- Set $g_n = f_1 - f_n \geq 0$, then $g_n \nearrow g$ where $g = f_1 - f$.
- (The hard part) Construct $s_n$ simple functions so that $s_n \leq g_n$ and $s_n \nearrow g$.
- Then $$0\leq \int g-g_n \leq \int g- s_n \to 0$$